# How can we add OUATH Connection Settings to Bots in the BotFramework?

Tags: oauth, botframework, teams-toolkit

When using TeamsFX to build bots for Microsoft Teams, bots (during development) are provisioned inside the BotFramework and can be managed here: https://dev.botframework.com/bots

These bots are not tied to any (of my) Azure subscriptions and seem to exist outside my tenant, but they are viewable by me.

In order to enable BOT SSO, I need to add [OAUTH credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-register-aad?tabs=windows#configure-oauth-connection-for-your-bot-resource) to the Bot.

If the bot were in the Azure Portal (Azure Bot Service), it is doable as follows:
[image: Azure Bot Service - OUATH Configuration]

However the Bot is not in the Azure Portal - it only exists [here](https://dev.botframework.com/bots).

How can I add OUATH credentials to the bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're 2 ways to enable BOT SSO:

1. Using the `TeamsBotSsoPrompt` prompt in `@microsoft/teamsfx` package. This configures the OAUTH credentials to your app's app settings instead of the Azure Bot service, so you can test your bot without an Azure subscription. You can refer the [document](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/tree/dev/packages/sdk#bot-sso) and the [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v2.2.0/bot-sso) to implement it.
2. Follow the document you're referring to enable BOT SSO. You need to take following manual steps to create an Azure Bot so you can configure your OAUTH credentials. After you successfully local debug your project with the new configuration, you should be able to find the Azure Bot resource in your subscription. The steps assume you use VS Code Teams Toolkit V5 to create a new bot project. Please update the paths and parameter values as needed.

   1. Delete your existing bot at https://dev.botframework.com/bots
   2. Create a new file at `infra/botRegistration/azurebot.parameters.json` with following content:

      ```
      {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
          "resourceBaseName": {
            "value": "bot${{RESOURCE_SUFFIX}}"
          },
          "botAadAppClientId": {
            "value": "${{BOT_ID}}"
          },
          "botAppDomain": {
            "value": "${{BOT_DOMAIN}}"
          },
          "botDisplayName": {
            "value": "bot-sso"
          }
        }
      }
      ```
   3. Replace the original snippet in `teamsapp.local.yml` with the new one:

      Original snippet:

      ```
      - uses: botFramework/create
        with:
          botId: ${{BOT_ID}}
          name: sso-bot
          messagingEndpoint: ${{BOT_ENDPOINT}}/api/messages
          description: ""
          channels:
            - name: msteams
      ```

      New snippet:

      ```
      - uses: arm/deploy # Deploy given ARM templates parallelly.
        with:
          subscriptionId: ${{AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}}
          resourceGroupName: ${{AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}}
          templates:
            - path: ./infra/botRegistration/azurebot.bicep
              parameters: ./infra/botRegistration/azurebot.parameters.json
              deploymentName: Create-resources-for-bot
          bicepCliVersion: v0.9.1
      ```

Comment: Another thing suggested by Microsoft Support  : Migrate the bot to a subscription using the MIGRATE feature in the Bot Framework Portal.